# Implementar Http Headers en Proyecto Ionic-Angular (Habilitar Cors en Api Rest)

Tags: c#, angular, ionic, typescript, rest

Estoy intentando consumir una ApiRest, pero debido a que le agregaron una validación por token, no logro consumirlo. Antes que le agregaran esa validación, si lograba consumirlo correctamente.

Como hay que enviar el token, no logro consumirlo. El error es el siguiente:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost:8100'; is therefore not allowed access. Le agregué los HttpHeaders –
```

AL probar el Api en postman, si funciona correctamente.

Actualmente el archivo rest.ts está de la siguiente forma:

```
            import { HttpClient, HttpHeaderResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    /*
      Generated class for the RestProvider provider.

      See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
      and Angular DI.
    */

    @Injectable()
    export class RestProvider {
      apiUrl = 'http://localhost:49533/api/Login';

      constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
        console.log('Hello RestProvider Provider');
      }

      logIn(username: string, password: string, pasword2: string) {
        const url = 'http://localhost:49533/api/Login';
        const body = JSON.stringify({
          Codigo: username,
          Usuario: password,
          Password: pasword2
        });
        //let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("X-CustomHttpHeader", "CUSTOM_VALUE")
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
          .set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT')
          .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        this.http.post(url, body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
          (data) => {

            console.log(data);
          },
          (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (err.error instanceof Error) {
              console.log('Client-side error occured.');
            } else {
              console.log('Server-side error occured.');
            }
          }
        );
      }

      /*getUsers() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          this.http.get(this.apiUrl + '/api/Login/123/123/123').subscribe(data => {
            resolve(data);
            console.log(data);
          }, err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        });
      }*/

      addUser(data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/users', JSON.stringify(data))
            .subscribe(res => {
              resolve(res);
            }, (err) => {
              reject(err);
            });
        });
      }
    }
```

Donde llamo al getUsers():

```
import { RestProvider } from '../../providers/rest/rest';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  users: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public restProvider: RestProvider) {
    this.logIn();
    //this.getUsers();
  }
  logIn(){
    this.restProvider.logIn("1234","1234","123123")
  }

  /*getUsers() {
    this.restProvider.getUsers()
    .then(data => {
      this.users = data;
      console.log(this.users);
    });
  }*/
}
```

Al revisar el Api Rest en C#:

```
public class TokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private static bool TryRetrieveToken(HttpRequestMessage request, out string token)
        {
            token = null;
            IEnumerable<string> authzHeaders;
            if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authzHeaders) || authzHeaders.Count() > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            var bearerToken = authzHeaders.ElementAt(0);
            token = bearerToken.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.Substring(7) : bearerToken;
            return true;
        }
}
```

revisé que lleva el request.Headers.tryGetValues y lleva lo siguiente:

```
  {Method: OPTIONS, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:49533/api/Login', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent, Headers:
    {
      Connection: keep-alive
      Accept: */*
      Accept-Encoding: gzip
      Accept-

Encoding: deflate
  Accept-Encoding: br
  Accept-Language: es-ES
  Accept-Language: es; q=0.9
  Host: localhost:49533
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0
  User-Agent: (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T)
  User-Agent: AppleWebKit/537.36
  User-Agent: (KHTML, like Gecko)
  User-Agent: Chrome/69.0.3497.100
  User-Agent: Mobile
  User-Agent: Safari/537.36
  Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
  Origin: http://localhost:8100
  Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-methods,access-control-allow-origin,content-type
  ApplicationInsights-RequestTrackingTelemetryModule-RootRequest-Id: 087a23b9-5473-47db-9b86-bb90f7a1cffa
}}
```

[image: Headers Null]

Y de ahí ya no pasa en el Api rest.

El token validation handler completo:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
namespace Ws
{
    public class TokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private static bool TryRetrieveToken(HttpRequestMessage request, out string token)
        {
            token = null;
            IEnumerable<string> authzHeaders;
            if (!request.Headers.TryGetValues("Authorization", out authzHeaders) || authzHeaders.Count() > 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            var bearerToken = authzHeaders.ElementAt(0);
            token = bearerToken.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? bearerToken.Substring(7) : bearerToken;
            return true;
        }

        protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpStatusCode statusCode;
            string token;
            //determine whether a jwt exists or not
            if (!TryRetrieveToken(request, out token))
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                //allow requests with no token - whether a action method needs an authentication can be set with the claimsauthorization attribute
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }

            try
            {
                const string sec = "401b09eab3c013d4ca54922bb802bec8fd5318192b0a75f201d8b3727429090fb337591abd3e44453b954555b7a0812e1081c39b740293f765eae731f5a65ed1";
                var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
                var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(sec));


                SecurityToken securityToken;
                JwtSecurityTokenHandler handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                TokenValidationParameters validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidAudience = "http://localhost:49533",
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:49533",
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    LifetimeValidator = this.LifetimeValidator,
                    IssuerSigningKey = securityKey,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false

                };
                //extract and assign the user of the jwt
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);
                HttpContext.Current.User = handler.ValidateToken(token, validationParameters, out securityToken);

                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
            }
            catch (SecurityTokenValidationException e)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode) { });
        }

        public bool LifetimeValidator(DateTime? notBefore, DateTime? expires, SecurityToken securityToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
        {
            if (expires != null)
            {
                if (DateTime.UtcNow < expires) return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Implementando la ayuda de @sioesi:

El proyecto de ionic corre en : http://localhost:8100/ y el api rest en http://localhost:49533/

En este caso el ionic.config.json :

```
{
  "name": "ionic3-angular43-rest",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {},
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api", 
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:49533"
    }
  ]
}
```

y el metodo de login:

```
return this.http.post('/api/api/Login', body, { headers: headers }).subscribe(
      (data) => {

        console.log(data);
      },
      (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        if (err.error instanceof Error) {
          console.log('Client-side error occured.');
        } else {
          console.log('Server-side error occured.');
        }
      }
```

Con este ultimo cambio, funciono correctamente.
Por su ayuda muchas gracias.

Comment: Tu problema no es Angular , tu problema es [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Gracias @JackNavaRow le hice algunos cambios al código, pero me devuelve el mismo error. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. Le agregué los HttpHeaders

Comment: debes configurar tu backend, tu frontend esta bien

Comment: Revisé el backend y realicé pruebas tratando de consumir el api rest, y unicamente con Angular me da ese error, con otras aplicaciones de escritorio no me devolvió ningún problema. Subí un poco más de información al respecto. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intenta implementar en el archivo `ionic.config.json` el arreglo `proxies`

```
"proxies": [
 {
  "path": "/api", //por ejemplo
  "proxyUrl": "http://tu_url"
 }
],
```

Y cuando hagas el llamado solo concatenas:

```
"/api/tu_servicio/"
```

Y el funcionamiento sigue siendo tal cual lo tienes, al utilizar la palabra que defines en el `path`, automaticamente entenderá que debe acceder a la url que defines y el llamado se ejecutará como si lo hiciera del mismo local.

El problema claramente son los cors y no tu backend, esta respuesta funciona solo cuando pruebas de forma web, con un `ionic serve`, desde la aplicación móvil no tendrás problemas.

Comment: si @raintrooper, aunque no se si sirva para dos ambientes que estan en el mismo local, pero con distinto puerto

Comment: Muchas graciass @sioesi, encontré mi error pero gracias a tus cambios logré que funcionara, muy agradecido.

Comment: De nada @raintrooper me alegro que haya funcionado.

Comment: @raintrooper recuerda que en el path, puedes escribir cualquier cosa, asi no se te confunde con "/api"

Comment: si de hecho ahí estaba mi error en este momento. Genial tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola @sioesi abrí una pregunta nueva. Por si tuvieras tiempo de ayudarme, muchas gracias. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207309/diferenciar-conexi%C3%B3n-en-app-ionic-al-momento-de-conectarse-a-api-rest

Comment: Se está debatiendo en Meta sobre las variantes de etiquetas de Ionic. ¿Te importaría darle una ojeada al debate como usuario importante en esa etiqueta? [Debate etiquetas Ionic](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4073/83)